# Although the quick sort method that I implemented works in Integer and String arrays, this method does not work in Car arrays

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, quicksort, partitioning

I tried to implement the quick sort of three objects: Integer, String, and Cars. When I tried to run the code for quick sorting, the quick sort method was working in Integer and String arrays but not Car arrays. Car class consists of two parametric variables: brand name (String) and model year (int). Here are the codes used for the quick sort.

```
public class SortArray
{
    private static <T extends Comparable <? super T>> int partition(T[] a, int first, int last)
    {
        int indexFromLeft = first;
        int indexFromRight = last;
        while(indexFromRight - indexFromLeft >= 1)
        {
            T pivotValue = a[first + (last - first) / 2];
            while(a[indexFromLeft].compareTo(pivotValue) < 0)
            {
                indexFromLeft++;
            }
            while(pivotValue.compareTo(a[indexFromRight]) < 0)
            {
                indexFromRight--;
            }
            if(indexFromLeft < indexFromRight)
            {
                T temp = a[indexFromLeft];
                a[indexFromLeft] = a[indexFromRight];
                a[indexFromRight] = temp;
                indexFromLeft++;
                indexFromRight--;
            }
        }
        return indexFromLeft;
    }
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void quickSortRecursively(T[] a, int first, int last)
    {
        if(first < last)
        {
            int pivot = partition(a, first, last);
            quickSortRecursively(a, first, pivot - 1);
            quickSortRecursively(a, pivot + 1, last);
        }
    }
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void quickSort(T[] data)
    {
        if(data == null || data.length == 0)
        {
             return;
        }
        quickSortRecursively(data, 0, data.length - 1);
    }
    public static <T> void display(T[] printedArray)
    {
        int index;
        for(index = 0; index < printedArray.length - 1; index++)
        {
            System.out.print(printedArray[index] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println(printedArray[index]);
    }
}
```

Here are the codes I used to demonstrate quick sort in main class.

```
public class MainSort
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Cars[] list3 = new Cars[8];
        list3[0] = new Cars("Mazda", 2004);
        list3[1] = new Cars("BMW", 1996);
        list3[2] = new Cars("Jaguar", 1989);
        list3[3] = new Cars("Tesla", 2017);
        list3[4] = new Cars("Acura", 2008);
        list3[5] = new Cars("Chrysler", 2012);
        list3[6] = new Cars("Volvo", 2001);
        list3[7] = new Cars("Pontiac", 1983);
        System.out.println("\nOriginal Array of Cars:");
        SortArray.display(list3);
        SortArray.quickSort(list3);
        SortArray.display(list3);
    }
}
```

By the way, I provide the car class as well.

```
public class Cars implements Comparable
{
    private String name;
    private int year;
    public Cars()
    {
        name = " ";
        year = 0;
    }
    public Cars(String brandName, int modelYear)
    {
        name = brandName;
        year = modelYear;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " " + year;
    }
    @Override;
    public int compareTo(Object[] t)
    {
        Cars c = (Cars) t;
        int y = c.getYear();
        if(year <= y)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to run the code, I found "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8" from the following lines:

```
while(a[indexFromLeft].compareTo(pivotValue) < 0)
```

in partition method,

```
int pivot = partition(a, first, last);
```

in quickSortRecursively method,

```
quickSortRecursively(data, 0, data.length - 1);
```

in quickSort method, and

```
SortArray.quickSort(list3);
```

in the main class.

I hope for the quick sort method to work well for the array of Car class along with Integer and String.

Comment: Step through with a debugger

Comment: You are sorting ONLY based on model year, and your `compareTo` does not work when two cars have the same model year.  There are cases where the pivot value will be compared to itself, and the wrong result will be returned, breaking the sort.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You are sorting ONLY based on model year, which may or may not be an issue
2. Your `compareTo()` method does not fulfill the required contract. It must return zero when two cars have the same sort key (in your case model year) but it does not. There are cases where the pivot value will be compared to itself, and the wrong result will be returned, breaking the sort.